# What is a sample size?

Tags: probability-theory

If you flip a coin 3 times and get the result $HHT$, you might say your sample size is 3.  On the other hand, $HHT$ is only a single element from the sample space of 3 flips, $\Omega = \{ HHH, HHT, \ldots, TTT\}$, so you might instead say your sample size is 1.

Let's say you want to perform inference on whether the coin is biased.  You might increase your sample size by flipping the coin more, say 100 times, and say your sample size is 100.  But again, this is just a single element from the sample space of 100 flips, so your sample size is still 1.

Indeed, the test statistic might be $$\hat{p}(\omega) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i(\omega)}{n}$$
where $X_i(\omega)$ is one if the $i^{th}$ term of $\omega$ is $H$ and zero otherwise.  Thus you have sampled one path from the "random experiment" space (sample space---only one $\omega$), but we still usually say the sample size is 100.

How should I reconcile the apparent conflict?

Comment: I do not see the conflict, you are just defining a different unit for the notion of sample, no? If you define a sample unit to be a realisation of a random variable you should be fine.

Comment: Let sample size correspond with the number of observations that are done in some statistical project. So $3$ in the first mentioned case and $100$ in the second. The minimalizes the chance on any misunderstandings. Also it matches with the concept [sample size determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first fix what is your "sample space" and what is meant by a "sample". Then the process of sampling is well defined.

If you think $\Omega$ as like a black box with a button then for every button press you a sample which is either $H$ or $T$. Pressing three times the button now  generates three samples $\Omega$ or "a sample with sample size 3".

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be the samples generated by pressing the button three times. Then the triplet $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ can take any value in the $\Omega\times\Omega\times\Omega$, which is simply the set of all possible samples.  On the other hand, I can even make two copies of the black box and each time I wish to sample I press both the buttons simultaneously and form the pair $(X_{i1},X_{i2})$. Then for such a type of sampling a sample for my experiment are then from the space $\Omega \times \Omega$ and if I sample thrice I pick an element from the set $(\Omega \times \Omega)^3$.